# IsPostBack which is more standard / performant

Tags: asp.net, postback, pageload, ispostback

i have came across many pre written asp.net web apps and many opensource asp.net web apps.

some where i had found

```
page_load()
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {

      //code logic
    }

}
```

where some other sites i had found

```
page_load()
{
    if(IsPostBack) return;
    //code logic

}
```

my question is which one of this is better code standard and which one of these is more performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance impact because the condition will be executed in both examples and the compiler may optimize the code anyway. It's just a matter of taste. The second one:

```
page_load()
{
    if(IsPostBack) return;
    //code logic

}
```

is known as a "Guard Clause". Read more at [wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause).